# how to connect odoo with asana?

Tags: odoo, asana-api, asana-connect

I want to connect my odoo with asana project.
but it display 
HTTPError: `HTTP Error 400: Bad Requesterror.`

```
def execute(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    params = {
        'client_id': '142025919&',
        'client_secret': '9691f60a6ca68&',
        'redirect_uri': 'urn:ief:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&',
        'state' :'somerandmstate'
    }
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    req = urllib2.Request('https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize%s?'%params)

    _logger.info(req)
    content = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=TIMEOUT).read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of recommendations for you:

1. If you want to connect to the Asana API using Python, I highly recommend our [client library](https://github.com/Asana/python-asana/).
2. The page you are trying to load is intended for human use. Your app should direct a human to that page in a browser. They will get back a token that can be pasted into your application. See [our OAuth documentation](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth) for more details.
3. If you do decide to continue using this approach, there are a couple of things you need to do to fix your request to work in `urllib2`. Firstly, your query parameters should come after the question mark. Secondly you need to URL encode them using `urllib.urlencode` (and then you don't need to include the `&`s in the `params` dictionary). For example

   ```
   params = urllib.urlencode({
       'client_id': 'someID',
       'client_secret': 'someSecret',
       'redirect_uri': 'urn:ief:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
       'state': 'somerandmstate'
   })
   req = urllib2.Request('https://app.asana.com/-/oauth_authorize?%s'%params)
   ```